# Why are some lines on my model drawn differently?

Tags: modeling

[image: Odd lines]

When I look at my object in edit mode I see there are quite a few lines that look different to how they look normally (kind of striped instead of solid black).

Why is this, and do I need to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are edges that have been marked as "sharp". In the tool panel in edit mode (press <kbd>T</kbd> if not visible) you can find the tools to mark them as smooth again:

[image: Select Smooth]